# Degree 5 sturm sequence formula? (isolator polynomials)

Tags: polynomials, roots

Given a quintic polynomial with a leading coefficient of 1:
$$p(x) = x^5 + bx^4 + cx^3 + dx^2 + ex + f$$
the paper at http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.133.2233&rep=rep1&type=pdf describes a concept called "isolator polynomials" which allow you to isolate the real roots of a polynomial.

It is proved (I think) that these isolator polynomials can be constructed in closed form using the polynomial's sterm sequence.

The paper presents a simple formula to determine two isolator polynomials that can be used for a quintic (bottom of page 3), however it does so with a quintic that has a $b$ value of 0. I would like the same type of formula but when b is not 0. The paper describes that these isolator polynomials can be constructed using sturm sequences, however I am not too familiar with them and my algebra is a little rusty.

I don't want to have to calculate the sturm sequence of my input polynomial every time for efficiency sake. I am only working with a quintic polynomial, and therefore the solution does not have to be general. How can I go about determining the isolator polynomials for when $b$ is not 0? Is there a formula for two terms of the sturm sequence of a quintic polynomial where those two term's degrees sum to 4 (5-1) as required by the paper?

Comment: Why not making a simple variable change such that the $b$ term becomes $0$? Something like $x = t - b/5$

Comment: I could do that, but in my mind a more general formula catering for the "b" term would be more efficient than computationally making a variable change each time. Unless you mean making a variable change purely on the maths side of things? Would that work fine?

Comment: If you have a general formula for $b = 0$ case, i.e. for the $t$ case, then you will get a general formula ($x$ case) thanks to this variable change. However, this general formula is likely to be much more complex. Performing a simple variable change doesn't seem really a challenge from the computational point of view.